# Where to put rich data markups?

Tags: seo, google, rich-snippets, microdata

I have a company website which I'm trying to make rich snippets.

Where should I put the `<span itemscope..` tags for Corporation?

In every page? Or just the "about us" and/or "contact" pages?

### P.S

Will it work if I use more than one page? For example, the address info is in "Contact" page, whereas employees info is in "About Us" page. can I merge two tags on different pages?

Comment: What are you planing to use? http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html

Comment: @guisasso Sorry I forgot to add that. Well, corporation I guess. It is an architecture company, so my choices are Organization and Corporation. Organization seems to be defined as "non-profit or non-governmental organizatio", so I think corporate is right. Is it?

Comment: No right or wrongs to your answer, you can have it within the footer on every page, you can it on the front page, you can have it on the about us, the choice goes on and on.

Comment: @bybe thanks. Which one do you think is better for SEO? I am afraid of getting a penalty from Google, since I heard it doesn't like duplicate things.

Comment: You can check microdata output by using below Google tool http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 1):

Microdata/RDFa markup is *per page*, not per site.

So you can duplicate your Microdata/RDFa on any page with appropriate content. At first you have your content, *then* your can mark it up with Microdata/RDFa. Because you have this content on several pages in the first place, it’s appropriate to semantically mark it up, too.

Parsers (including search engines) will decide for themselves which markup for which page to use.

Answer (score 0):

***Duplicate Content***

Google is smarter than you think and I believe you need to research on what qualifies as duplicate content. Google's bot are able to detect the content area of each site, so even through you may have an address or tagline repeated lots of time in various sections such as a box within the  content, the footer, the header and so on you will not be punished, otherwise every webmaster on the planet would be complaining that there footers, logos and so on would be hurting their rankings.

Duplicate content is considered the same content repeated once or more on another page within the content area of your site. And containing snippets of other pages such as an address unless the pages are identically the same would not merit as duplicate content.

**Rich Snippets SEO**

At present you should consider Rich Snippets as a perk to your mark up, they do not improve SEO rankings directly as I'm assuming that is your belief, Google has yet to flick the switch when rich snippets actually contribute to your Rankings. Rich Snippets can improve your click rates depending on what Niche, Products and Rich Snippets your using. Currently Google does not even take advantage of most Schema Items, Google only displays some and not most.

**Repeat use of Rich Snippets**

The same as any other content Google will be able to establish repeated content regardless of the markup, many webmasters repeat the schema logo markup in the header and many repeat the local business Schema in the footer. So repeating it across the site should not be a problem.

**Repeat use of the same rich snippets on the same page**

The only issue you should be aware of is that if your using the exact markup in say an address in the footer and then again on the same page on the content page then this would be incorrect, you should only need to mark up one which ideally would be the one in the footer.

Comment: OK, thanks. I, too, guess that Google is smart :) And no, my real aim is to have made a good site. Since the customers' goal is not many visitors, but rather, seeing a nice website, about a company that designs, so I just wanted to learn how to do rich snippets. Thanks for pointing out one markup is enough :)